# jquery not working well on node-webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-webkit

I am practicing node-webkit as a nodejs beginner.
My main page is a simple `html` page including a `main.js` script

*I've installed jquery using `npm install jquery`*

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
...
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo">Hi! </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
// main.js
const $ = require('jquery')

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#demo').click(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + 'Hi! ')
  })
})
```

If I load jquery in my `index.html` like `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>` it works well, but if I require jquery in my `main.js` it doesn't!

I've already tested:

- `main.js` is properly including and working with native js methods (like `document.getElementById('demo').onclick = ...`)
- Other node modules or libraries such as `vue`, `lodash` or natives like `fs`, `url` work well. So require function works good.
- While I'm requiring jquery as above, inline `<script>`s doesn't work as well.

Also I realized `$(document).ready(...)` works! But the real problem is that `$('#demo')` is undefined! (I checked the console-I'm using SDK version of node-webkit)

I don't know if it's because of node-webkit or something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution,
I should define jquery like this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

this is simply because of *variable scopes* in ECMAS

so if I define it like this, I can use it everywhere

Comment: the code is working but ... the $('elementSelector').html() is not working. Any clue why?